# Rails groupdate gem pg error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, scope

I have a Rails 3.2.14 app where I'm trying to use the `chartkick` and `groupdate` gem to generate some charts.  I've installed both gems, and I'm trying to do some test queries from the console on my `Call` model.

`Call.group_by_day(:created_at)`

I raise an exception and get the following error:

```
 Call Load (8.8ms)  SELECT "calls".* FROM "calls" WHERE (created_at IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY (DATE_TRUNC('week', (created_at::timestamptz - INTERVAL '6 day' - INTERVAL '0' hour) AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago') + INTERVAL '6 day' + INTERVAL '0' hour) AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  column "calls.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT "calls".* FROM "calls"  WHERE (created_at IS NOT NULL...
               ^
: SELECT "calls".* FROM "calls"  WHERE (created_at IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY (DATE_TRUNC('week', (created_at::timestamptz - INTERVAL '6 day' - INTERVAL '0' hour) AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago') + INTERVAL '6 day' + INTERVAL '0' hour) AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago
```

Is there something I'm supposed to do to make this work?  Is there some sort of scope I need to create to make this work?  I'm new to the gems so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I wasn't calling this correctly.

I needed to call `Call.group_by_day(:created_at).count` to make this work.